# Faking ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy with Mocha in Capybara (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mocking, capybara, mocha.js

I have a very simple data structure: a `User` has_many `filters` and a `Filter` belongs_to a `user`.  For my tests, I am using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) and [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) (no rspec).

I am struggling to adequately stub an `ActiveRecord` collection of `Filter`s.  This is what I have currently:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TestExample < Capybara::Rails::TestCase

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    def setup
        # Create some mock filters:
        f1 = Filter.new
        f1.stubs(:id).returns(1)
        f1.stubs(:user_id).returns(1)
        f1.stubs(:title).returns("First Filter")
        f1.stubs(:value).returns(123)

        f2 = Filter.new
        f2.stubs(:id).returns(2)
        f2.stubs(:user_id).returns(1)
        f2.stubs(:title).returns("Second Filter")
        f2.stubs(:value).returns(456)

        fake_filters = [f1, f2]
        user.stubs(:filters).returns(fake_filters)

    end

    def test_user_has_correct_number_of_mocked_filters
        assert_equal(user.filters.count, 2)
    end

    def test_users_mocked_filters_have_correct_ids
        assert_equal(user.filters.pluck(:id), [1, 2]) # ERROR
    end

end
```

The second test throws an error, since their is no `pluck()` method for an `Array`.

How would this be accomplished?  I want the tests to behave as if there are indeed records in the `Filter` table.

Comment: The setup code is also not DRY at all, so I know there must be another way of doing it.

Comment: Capybara is for integration/feature tests, you shouldn't really be mocking anything in a test derived from Capybara::Rails::TestCase since its purpose is to test the entire stack including real DB objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be mocking objects when using Capybara, it's for full integration/feature tests.  Instead you should build them using factory_girl like you are for user

```
factory :user do
  # you current user factory code
  # stays here

  factory :user_with_filters do
    transient do
      filters_count 2
    end
    after(:create) do |user, proxy|
      create_list(:filter, proxy.filters_count, user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

and then instead of `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` do `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_filters) }`

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. In my actual application, the creation of a 'Filter' triggers a bunch of worker processes that query a lot of data, and it therefore takes some time. I was hoping to avoid all that by stubbing. But as you say, an Integration test should use actual DB objects, so I'll do that.

Comment: @BradleyMarques You may want to look at decoupling the creation of the worker processes a bit so you can create filters without doing that sometimes, to aid in testing.

Answer (score 0):

Pluck is a method restricted to ActiveRecord::Relation, so unless you also stub a method on `fake_filters` called pluck, just like you did on Filter

However, what I would do is just use `.map(&:id)` instead of `.pluck(:id)`. The difference between map and pluck is that map is not efficient during querying since it will do a `SELECT * FROM filters` instead of `SELECT id FROM filters` in the case of pluck. Map also allows querying anything the object responds to, not only the active record attributes. However, here, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I really need to test as if it is an ActiveRecord collection.  In my application code, I am using `pluck` elsewhere, and if the collections were mocked, then it would fail.  It's therefore better to use real database entries as per TomWalpole's answer.